# What is the function of "-ter" in words "laughter" and "daughter"?

Tags: etymology, affixes, morphemes

The word "**laugh**" exists in English, but not "***daugh**", even though both have a *-ter* word and their forms are similar.

I can't find the function of the morpheme "-ter" here, which  may be irrelevant to the "-ter" in "**enter**" or "**utter**", which are a comparative suffix (from PIE ***-tero**) and a frequentative suffix **"-er"**(of unknown origin to me), respectively.

Comment: I'm not sure that *-ter* is a morpheme at all, but it seems that the sources of this ending are not the same: *laughter* was *\*hlahtraz* in Proto-Germanic whereas *daughter* was *\*dochter*. These words only have similar modern spellings by accident, as is suggested by their very different pronunciations.

Comment: A general, methodological note on your question. In Modern English, words like "enter", "utter", and "daughter" are monomorphemic. As for the suffix -ter in Modern English, it is recognized/analyzed/present in two words only, laughter::laugh and slaughter::slay. However, if you're interested in comparative/historical linguistics, it's another story. In other words, your question, as is, is ambiguous.

Comment: @Alex B: What about rafter:roof.

Comment: @PeterShor, if you look again at my examples (borrowed from Laurie Bauer's book), the pattern is "verb+TER=noun", and the meaning of thus derived noun is "an act/instance of verbing". As for rafter and roof, well, I fail to see how these are related, even diachronically. The OED says OE hrof 'roof' and OE ræfter 'rafter, beam'.

Comment: @AlexB. Hi~Alex! I hope to find out the etymology of the word "daughter" diachronically, because I'am not sure whether the "-ter" here is just the kinship suffix "-ter" in L. pater and mater, and if so, what does "daugh" in the word mean?

Comment: @archenoo it is not known by the current science. Some linguists proposed that it could mean "milker" or "who prepares food" but these suggestions are mostly rejected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There was the agent suffix -ter- of PIE. It was used for creation of terms for relatives and for creation of agent nouns.

Suffix -ter- was used to create a noun for person whose function or profession was to perform the action (irrespective whether he actually did it) while the o-grade of it -tor- was used to denote a person who just did the action. The combination of suffixes -a̯-ter- was used for some relatives.

Thus the term for daughter in PIE was ***dhuga̯tēr***.

The same suffix in zero-grade, "-tr-" in combination with inanimate ending "-om" was used for creating words for tools, such as ***a̯ero̯trom*** "plow", ***u̯estrom*** "wear", ***tere̯trom*** "auger", ***costrom*** "knife".

Thus regular PIE rules suggest that a combination of the root for laugh, "kleg-" plus "-tr-" such as in "klegtrom" should give a non-animate noun related to laugh. In Pre-Germanic the ending could change from inanimate -om to masculine -os to render (via metathesis) *hlahtraz in Proto-Germanic.

It is more possible though that the word by this same process was formed already after Germanic branch split of PIE because other branches do not show use of the -tr- suffix with this root.

By the way, of course, the PIE superlative -ter-os was also another use of the same suffix. Thus  "gela̯teros" would mean "more joyful". The word "enter" (from Latin *intra-*) is another example of use of this suffix with adverbs: ***e̯en*** "in" + "-ter-om" -> ***e̯enterom*** "intestines", of which locative case is ***e̯enteri*** "inside".

Comment: Very interesting!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!it's really informative and helpful!

Comment: *Laughter* is not related to the Greek root *gela-*: PIE *g gives Germanic *k, not *h. It's also far from certain that the suffix of *laughter* is related to either PIE *-ter (kinship noun/agent noun) or *-trom (instrument), since it's semantically quite different from both.

Comment: What theory of Indo-European linguistics does this answer adhere to? I haven't ever seen semivowel versions of the "full" vowels /*e *o *a/. Are those laryngeals? Why show them as semivowels?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be much of a leap to suggest this as an example of a "cranberry morpheme"? A somewhat fossilised style of inflection, in that it no longer carries any distinct meaning in itself, but nonetheless is still quite pertinent to the meaning of the the word itself.

I've also put a little more thought into it and have come up with daughter, sister, from English, as well as mater and pater from Latin as examples of famillial relations employing -ter.

Comment: Of course, as is was suffix for relatives: ***mea̯tēr***,  ***pa̯tēr***, ***dhuġa̯tēr***, ***bhrea̯tēr***, ***i̯ena̯tēr***, but NOT word for sister which was ***su̯esōr*** and only later accuired the modern form due to levelling.

Answer (score -4):

Even with English being a third language to me, the grammatical purport of the suffix "-ter" in words such as "laughter" is easily deducible with only a second's worth of though expended. The affixation of "-ter" is an obvious, though uncommon from my experience, inflectional suffix serving to change a verb, as in "laugh", into a noun. Compare "He laughed at the joke I had told him..." to "His laughter at the joke I had told him...".