# Why do mother/father/brother/sister/daughter all end in '-er'?

Tags: english, proto-indo-european

Is it just a coincidence, or was there a reason why they ended in '-er'? I know that all of them derive from PIE, where they also ended in '-er'.

Also, is this '-er' the same '-er' particle, as in 'fighter', 'liar', 'runner', etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already answerred it, so this is a copy of my [previous answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/2878/624):

There was the agent suffix -ter- of PIE. It was used for creation of terms for relatives and for creation of agent nouns.

Suffix -ter- was used to create a noun for person whose function or profession was to perform the action (irrespective whether he actually did it) while the o-grade of it -tor- was used to denote a person who just did the action. The combination of suffixes -a̯-ter- was used for some relatives.

Thus the term for daughter in PIE was ***dhuga̯tēr***.

The same suffix in zero-grade, "-tr-" in combination with inanimate ending "-om" was used for creating words for tools, such as ***a̯ero̯trom*** "plow", ***u̯estrom*** "wear", ***tere̯trom*** "auger", ***costrom*** "knife".

By the way, of course, the PIE superlative -ter-os was also another use of the same suffix. Thus  "***gela̯teros***" would mean "more joyful". The word "enter" (from Latin *intra-*) is another example of use of this suffix with adverbs: ***e̯en*** "in" + "-ter-om" -> ***e̯enterom*** "intestines", of which locative case is ***e̯enteri*** "inside".

The English suffex -er does not have anything in connection, it is believed to be borrowed from Latin -arius.

Comment: I found this in [Google Books](http://books.google.bg/books?id=DJDjNp6wODoC&lpg=PA70&ots=AC854wKLxT&dq=Indo-European%20kinship%20suffix%20*-ter&pg=PA70#v=onepage&q&f=false), where the author claims that kinship suffix *-ter cannot be reliably connected to the agent suffix *-ter. So is it accepted by linguistics that they are the same *-ter?

Comment: Proto-Indo-European is a field where hardly anything is universally "accepted by linguistics". Everything is open for informed discussion.

Comment: @sashoalm what do you mean under "connected"? Common etymological origin or something else?

Comment: I meant common etymological origin, yes. That was the word used in the text from Google Books, actually. Btw, does Latin '-tor' as in protector come for PIE *-ter? Also in Slavic there is an agent suffix that ends in -ar.

Comment: @sashoalm yes, Latin -tor is exactly the same suffix (although in "protector" it is fused with the stem "protect"). The Slavic -ar is a different suffix, related to English -er and thought to be borrowed from Latin -arius at very early times. The etymology or PIE "-ter-" is unknown.

Answer (score 3):

The Indo-European words for “father, mother, sister, brother” are all stems in –r, which appears as -ṛ, -er, -ēr, -ōr in different forms of these words.

The English agent suffix –er, as in "fighter", goes back to a proto-Germanic *-ārijaz, which is widely held to be ancient borrowing from the Latin suffix –ārius.

There is no connection between these.

Comment: "are all stems in –r" - What does this mean? I couldn't figure it out. Is this a class/type of words in PIE?

Answer (score 3):

This -er is no way a particle, it is probably a very ancient Indo-European suffix of unknown meaning, not connected with the modern English agent -er suffix. These words belong to the so called athematic r-stem nouns (nouns with stems ending not in a vowel, but in -r-). Not only kinship terms belonged to that noun class, the word "water" also belongs to it (Hittite 'watar', 15th century BC).

Comment: Also "daiver" (brother in law), which is preserved in some Slavic languages, but not English.

Comment: @sashoalm - You are absolutely right. Also, the Russian "свёкор" (father-in-law), which is cognate with the Latin "socer", probably file here.

Comment: And many more, e.g. Sanskrit naptar- "grandson" (from the same root as Latin nepos, but a different stem formation).